# How can I write a Integer to a FileStream in C#?

Tags: c#, byte, filestream

I was wondering if someone can help me solve a issue I have run into while playing with FileStreams. I have been trying to send an integer, 50, to a FileStream and write its value onto a File. However, it writes 2 to the file instead of 50. I know the ASCII representation of 50 is 2, so am not sure if this is part of the issue. If anyone has any pointers, I'd really appreciate it!

Here is my relevant code:
From the main function:

```
string testMessage = "Testing writing some arbitrary string to a streama";
int tmL = testMessage.Length;
byte bb = Convert.ToByte(tmL);
SendByteStrem(bb);
```

And here is my streaming function:

```
public static void SendByteStrem(byte c){
    using (Stream ioStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\db0201\Desktop\stream.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)){
          ioStream.WriteByte(c);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you want 50 to be written in the file instead of 2?

Comment: cast it? (`int)c`

Comment: Can you please [edit] to clarify how you want your file look like? Do you want text output (very unusual to use `Stream` for such task) or binary data (that is what you are doing... but file called ".txt" causing confusion). Also question title asks about "integer" (4 bytes) but code sample writes single byte...

Comment: Yep I am trying to convert 50 to a byte, send it to a FileStream and write "50" in the file. Great point about integer being 4 bytes, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you haven't explicitly stated your goal, i will answer the question for what it is.

The easiest way to write to a file would be to use [`File.WriteAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8) which essentially opens a [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8) (which in-turn is open a `FileStream`) and calls [`Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.write?view=netframework-4.8)

> Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes
>   the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, "50")
```

or

```
var myInt = 50;
File.WriteAllText(fileName, myInt.ToString())
```

If you wanted to use the `StreaWriter` exclusively

```
using (varwriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))  
    writer.Write(myInt.ToString());
```

If you wanted more configuration over the underlying `FileStream`

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew)))  
   writer.Write(myInt.ToString());
```

if you just want to use a `FileStream` then things get a bit more manual as you will need to convert things to *bytes*

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew)) 
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myInt.ToString());
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! It sounds like ToString can find the character code to write a '5' and the character code to write a '0' on the file, rather than write the ASCII representation of 50 from the ASCII table, is this correct? Inside my File Stream cluster, now it works!

Comment: @lightwingduck yes it converts it to a string, which then gets converted to utf8 bytes, so its all sorted